# PyQt : 'Async Function' Starter Function

Tags: python, variables, asynchronous, pyqt

First of all, I don't know if what I'm trying to do is the right way. I want to create a function that creates async functions.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=1)

def asyncstarter(self,func):
    pool.apply_async(
        func,              
    )  

def looper(self):
    while i < 100 :
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1 
self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.asyncstarter('self.looper'))
```

To be clear, I'm not an experienced programmer, I looked at pyqt's qthreads but it was hard for me to understand.

Anyway, is it possible to use a variable inside apply_sync ? As seen in the code, "func" will be sent to it depending on the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best one but I found a solution myself (although it looks ridicilous) ;

```
def asyncstarter(self,func):
    command = "pool.apply_async(%s)" %func
    eval(command)
    start = command
```